# Problema bucles for

Tags: java, array, método

Tengo 2 arrays, uno lo introduce el usuario *matrizUsuario* el otro *matrizDefecto* lo crea la maquina. El usuario tiene que intentar adivinar la matriz de la maquina de tal manera que he creado 2 if como podeis ver, uno dice si esta el numero en su sitio y otro si esta el numero  pero no en el mismo sito.
El problema viene cuando en *matrizDefecto* tiene 2 números repetidos. Imaginar que la secuencia de *matrizDefecto* es 1,3,4,2,4 y el usuario introduce esa misma secuencia en *matrizUsuario*. Por mucho que sean identicas según mis condiciones *if* el numero *4* de la ultima posición me sale como ("El numero 'x' esta pero no en su sitio ya que con la variable que tengo booleana en el momento que encuentra un numero igual ejecuta el if y ya sale del bucle for, no le da la opción a llegar al segundo *4* de la matriz *matrizDefecto*.

```
for(int i=0;i<matrizUsuario.length;i++) {
     boolean encontrado=false;
        for(int j=0;j<matrizDefecto.length&&encontrado==false;j++) {
            if(j==i&&matrizUsuario[i]==matrizDefecto[j]){
                    System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[i]+" existe y esta en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
                encontrado=true;
                }
            if(i!=j&&matrizUsuario[i]==matrizDefecto[j]) {
                System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[i]+" esta, pero no en su sitio");
                incorrecto=true;
                encontrado=true;
            }
           }
    }
```

Comment: Es que explicar mi problema es difícil de redactar, lo siento.

Comment: Y aunque no lo creas, lo que pasa es correcto. Ese primer 4 esta en la misma posicion, y en otra posicion. De alguna forma, tenes que marcar los que estan en la misma posicion, y despues solo buscar los que estan pero en distintas posiciones...

Comment: Sí, no digo que el programa lo haga mal, simplemente no encuentro la manera de que me vaya a mirar el segundo 4 obviando el 4 anterior porque en algunos casos me interesará que compruebe el primero y en otros casos el segundo dependiendo de la posicion del for _matrizUsuario_

Comment: Entonces volvemos a mi planteo original.. primero fijate si son exactamente iguales. Si no lo son, marca los iguales, esos no los mires mas.. y despues de lo que sobra, fijate si estan en otra posicion ;)

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89892/discussion-on-question-by-winnie-problema-bucles-for).

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta cuesta un poco de entender pero creo que puedo responderla

Tu problema es que al pasar por el primer 4 cambias "encontrado"  a true, y no la vuelves a cambiar hasta que completas una iteración completa del bucle externo. Vuelve a poner la variable a false al principio del bucle interno y no tendrás el problema.

Prueba así:

```
for(int i=0;i<matrizUsuario.length;i++) {

    for(int j=0;j<matrizDefecto.length&&encontrado==false;j++) {
        boolean encontrado=false;
        if(j==i&&matrizUsuario[i]==matrizDefecto[j]){
                System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[i]+" existe y esta en su sitio");
            incorrecto=true;
            encontrado=true;
            }
        if(i!=j&&matrizUsuario[i]==matrizDefecto[j]) {
            System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[i]+" esta, pero no en su sitio");
            incorrecto=true;
            encontrado=true;
        }
       }
}
```

Igualmente, no entiendo la función de las variables booleanas en tu código. Yo haría un contandor sobre el primer if y cuando sea igual a la longitud de la matriz habrías averiguado la combinación correcta.

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0;i<matrizUsuario.length;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<matrizDefecto.length&&encontrado==false;j++) {
        if(j==i&&matrizUsuario[i]==matrizDefecto[j]){
                System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[i]+" existe y esta en su sitio");
            counter++;
            }
        if(i!=j&&matrizUsuario[i]==matrizDefecto[j]) {
            System.out.println("El numero "+matrizUsuario[i]+" esta, pero no en su sitio");

        }
       }
}

if  ( counter == matrizDefecto.length){
System.out.println("Combinación adivinada");
}
```

Comment: Esa solución no me serviría porque porque la variable booleana no puedo iniciarla debajo del for si la estoy usando en la condición de este mismo.

Comment: Tienes razón. Puedes iniciarla también antes del bucle externo. Igualmente creo que no aportan ( las variables booleanas) nada: Yo las quitaba del código.  ¿Las vas a necesitar después?

Comment: La variable incorrecta la utilizo para en el caso de que sea false al final de for decir que no hay ninguna coincidencia.Y la de encontrada servia porque si no la pongo,cuando el arrayDefecto tiene 2 números repetidos me mostraba (1-en el caso de que diera la casualidad que has puesto el numero donde toca: (el numero esta y bien puesto) y acontinuación continuaba el for y mostraba cuando encontraba otra vez ese numero :(el numero esta pero no en su sitio). De esta manera consigo que salga del array y no me desvele que en la matrizDefecto hay otro numero que yo no he puesto.No sé si me explico.

Comment: Perdón, pero la verdad es que no. Yo utilizaría un contador para ver la coincidencia de número y posición y otro para ver las coincidencias sin posición y mira el valor de estos al final.

Answer (score 0):

Como se ha mencionado en los comentarios, el problema está en la forma en que realizas las comprobaciones.

Yo voy a plantear un forma de realizar dichas comprobaciones lo más aproximado posible a lo que propones en tu pregunta, y le haré un cambio que considero una mejora, ya eso lo decides tu.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea comparar 2 matrices: `matrizDefecto` generada por el sistema y `matrizUsuario` introducida por el usuario. Ambas matrices contienen números enteros. Cada valor introducido por el usuario se compara con los valores de la matriz de sistema. Se debe informar lo siguiente para cada comparación:

1. El valor coincide en número y posición.
2. El valor existe pero en otra posición.
3. El valor no existe.

Mi mejora consiste en informar la cantidad de veces que existe el valor del usuario, quedando la salida de la siguiente forma:

1. El valor coincide en número y posición.
2. El valor existe `n` veces pero en otra(s) posición(es).
3. El valor no existe.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La forma en la que vamos a realizar la comparación es la siguiente:

1. Tomamos un elemento de la matriz de usuario y comparamos con un elemento en la misma posición de la matriz de sistema.
2. Si el elemento es igual, informamos al usuario que dicho elemento coincide en valor y posición.
3. Si el elemento no es igual, comparamos el elemento con cada elemento de la matriz de sistema para buscar coincidencias.
4. Si encontramos coincidencias informamos la cantidad de las mismas.

Dicho esto, dejo el código. Mi programa es tipo desafío. No genera una matriz aleatoria, solo usa una que el O.P. da como ejemplo, para probar el razonamiento y que pueda decidir si la respuesta es la deseada.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guessArrays {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creamos una matriz por defecto, se puede implementar
    // un código que llene de forma aleatoria la matrizDefecto
    int[] matrizDefecto = {1,3,4,2,4};

    // instanciamos una matrizUsuario con el tamaño de matrizDefecto
    int[] matrizUsuario = new int[matrizDefecto.length];

    // cantidad de intentos que le daremos al usuario
    int guesses = 5;

    // variable que indicará si todos los valores han sido acertados en posición correcta
    boolean allMatch = true;

    // variable que indicará si un valor está en posicion correcta
    boolean match = false;

    // variable que indicará si un valor existe en nuestra matriz
    boolean exist = false;

    // variable que almacenrá la cantidad de veces que aparece un valor en nuestra matriz
    int count = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // comenzamos el desafio
    while(guesses > 0) {
      // asumimos que todos los valores coinciden
      allMatch = true;

      System.out.println("\nLe quedan " + guesses + " intentos.");
      System.out.println("Introduzca los 5 valores de la matriz:");
      // leemos los valores que introduce el usuario
      for(int i = 0; i < matrizDefecto.length; i++) {
        matrizUsuario[i] = sc.nextInt();
      }

      // recorremos los valores uno a uno para buscar coincidencias
      for(int j = 0; j < matrizUsuario.length; j++) {
        // para cada valor primero establecemos las variables
        match = false;
        exist = false;
        count = 0;

        // si hay coincidencia de valor y posición
        if(matrizUsuario[j] == matrizDefecto[j]) {
          match = true;
        } else {
          // si no coincide valor
          allMatch = false;
          // recorremos matrizDefecto para buscar coincidencias
          for(int k = 0; k < matrizDefecto.length; k++) {
            // si hay una coincidencia
            if(matrizUsuario[j] == matrizDefecto[k]) {
              // el valor existe
              exist = true;
              // contamos las veces que aparece
              count++;
            }
          }
        }

        // mostramos el resultado de la comparación
        if(match) {
          System.out.println("El valor: " + matrizUsuario[j] + " esta en la posicion correcta.");
        } else {
          if(exist) {
            if (count > 1) {
              System.out.println("El valor: " + matrizUsuario[j] + " existe " + count + " veces pero en otra posicion.");
            } else {
              System.out.println("El valor: " + matrizUsuario[j] + " existe " + count + " vez pero en otra posicion.");
            }
          } else {
            System.out.println("El valor: " + matrizUsuario[j] + " no existe.");
          }
        }
      }
      // si el usuario acierta todo, salimos del while
      if(allMatch) {
        break;
      } else {
        guesses--;
      }
    }

    // mostramos el resultado del desafio
    if(allMatch) {
      System.out.println("\nHa acertado, felicidades");
    } else {
      System.out.println("\nLo siento, sera en otra oportunidad");
    }
  }
}
```

Espero que esta respuesta te ayude a resolver el problema. Saludos.